# to alphabetically order a name and score from a textfile which joins the users name and their highest score

Tags: loops, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

```
if Class.lower() == ("classa"):
    from collections import defaultdict #Automatically creates an empty list
    scores = defaultdict(list)#Creates the variable called scores


    with open('ClassA.txt') as f:#Opens the text file for classA
            for score, name in zip(f, f):#Makes the users 
                    scores[name.strip()].append(int(score))#Appends scores to a list as you cant have the same key twice in a dictionary.
```

the text file looks like this:
10
Mohammad
8
Mohammad
9
Mohammad
5
Bob
4
Bob
7
Bob
3
Micheal
2
Micheal
5
Micheal
8
James
6
James
7
James
6
Tony
4
Tony
7
Tony
4
Sara
6
Sara
6
I would like to be able to print the users highest score from the three scores then i would like to print the users scores from highest to lowest e.g mohammad first since he got 10 points and then finally i would also like to print the users scores by average from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer you question if I understood it correctly.

```
import re
for score, name in re.findall("(\d+) (\w+)", f.read()):  # using regular expressions module to parse the scores and names
    scores[name.strip()].append(int(score))

# Set highest scores first in list and print those sorted
# sort the individual scores high to low, list format[(name, scores),...,]
score_list = [(name, sorted(scores[name], reverse=True)) for name in scores]
# sort the named scores high to low by highest score(x[0] sorts names alphabetic)
score_list = sorted(score_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print("Highest sorted")
for name, v in score_list:  # v contains the individual scores
    print(v[0], name)  # Print highest score which is at 0 index and print the name

print()
print("highest to lowest")
for name, v in score_list:  # v contains the individual scores
    print(v, name)  # Print scores and name

print()
print("highest average")
average_scores = []
# iterate through the ordered score list and append the average score to the average_scores list
for name, v in score_list:  # v contains the individual scores
    average_scores.append((name, sum(v) / len(v)))
# sort average_scores high to low
sorted_average_scores = sorted(average_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# iterate through sorted_average_scores and print the rounded average, non-sorted individual scores, and name
for name, average in sorted_average_scores:
    print(round(average), scores[name], name)
```

Output:

```
Highest sorted
10 Mohammad
8 James
7 Tony
7 Bob
6 Sara
5 Micheal

highest to lowest
[10, 9, 8] Mohammad
[8, 7, 6] James
[7, 6, 4] Tony
[7, 5, 4] Bob
[6, 4] Sara
[5, 3, 2] Micheal

highest average
9 [10, 8, 9] Mohammad
7 [8, 6, 7] James
6 [6, 4, 7] Tony
5 [5, 4, 7] Bob
5 [4, 6] Sara
3 [3, 2, 5] Micheal
```

Comment: This works very well and has answered the question I had so thank you very much :D, is there any change I could ask you to add some more comments to your code so that I know what each line does that would be fantastic. Also at first it returned an error were it was not opening the file however I fixed that with this "with open('ClassA.txt') as f:" just before the first for loop.